# Get Userdata from database by Login Sessions Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i'm trying to make a login system. When user already login it will show user personal data like name, email or something. I'm try to modify the login code but doesn't work. Maybe someone can help.

Here is my code.
**Controller**

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_login extends CI_Controller
{

     public function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->model('Model_user');
          $this->load->library('form_validation');

     }

     public function index()
     {

                 $this->load->view('user/user_login');

     }

     function aksi_login(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $where = array(
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password,
      'status' => 1
     );
    $cek = $this->Model_user->cek_login('tb_user',$where)->num_rows();
    if($cek > 0){

     $data_session = array(
      'username' => $username,
      'status' => "userlogin"
      );

     $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
     redirect('user/user_dash');

    }else{
       $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_data', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="font-size:12px">
      <center><b>Sorry !!</b> Username / Password is not correct.
     </center>
     </div>');
      redirect('user/user_login');
    }
   }

   function logout(){
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('user/user_login');
   }


}?>
```

**Model**

```html
 function cek_login($table,$where){
  return $this->db->get_where($table,$where);

 }
```

I'm can make username session appear,

```html
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username') ?> it's working.
```

But try to show name it doesnt appear. Appreciate any kind help. Thank you

Comment: you "can" or "cant" make the username appear? also don't store users passwords as plaintext and use `password_verify()` and related php functions. also consider using a pre-rolled solution like ion_auth

Comment: i can make username appear, but not the full name from user. sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
$query = $this->Model_user->cek_login('tb_user',$where);
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    $user = $query->row();
    $data_session = array(
        'username' => $username,
        'status' => "userlogin",
        'name' => $user->name,
        );

    $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
    redirect('user/user_dash');


} {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_data', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="font-size:12px">
        <center><b>Sorry !!</b> Username / Password is not correct.
    </center>
    </div>');
        redirect('user/user_login');
}
```

**For this to work, there must be a `name` column in the table `tb_user`**

Comment: thanks i will try, sure column in the table is already named 'tb_user'.

Comment: will this work for other column ? example 'address' ?

Comment: The `row()` method returns all the columns that were selected in the query and return it as an object so if you have an address column in your table you can access it like `$user->address`.

Comment: Got it mate. I'm trying to create profile user now, if find some problem i will ask again. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the full name in the session too.
Try editing this

```
$cek = $this->Model_user->cek_login('tb_user',$where)->num_rows();
    if($cek > 0){

        $data_session = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'status' => "userlogin"
            );
```

to this

```
$cek = $this->Model_user->cek_login('tb_user',$where);
    if($cek->num_rows() == 1){
         $row=$cek->result_array()[0]; //returns an array of results, pick the first

        $data_session = array(
            'fullname' =>  $row['fullname'], //assuming column name is 'fullname'
            'username' =>  $username,
            'status'   => "userlogin",
            );
```